# Value assigned in array changes, and I do not understand why

Tags: c, arrays, fgets

so I am pretty new to C programming, and am having a problem that I truly do not understand. I am reading lines from a file, and trying to store each line (as a string) in an array. I am then using strtok on that line to parse another value out of the line. For some reason, the value I put in the array changes after I use strtok. Code is below:

```
while(fgets(readLine, 100, inFile) != NULL) { 
    printf("j = %d\n", j);
    puts(readLine); 
    machineList[j] = readLine;
    puts(machineList[j]); //the value of machineList[j] at this point is equal
                          // to the current readLine 

    int i=0;

    day = strtok(readLine, " ,");

    puts(machineList[j]); //the value of machineList[j] at this point is no
                          //longer what it was at the previously noted point

    while(i<3) {
        day=strtok(NULL, " ,");
        i++;
    }
    dayList[j]=atoi(day);

    printf("Day is: %d\n\n", dayList[j] );  //these values come out as expected
    j++;

}
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening? I don't understand, since its not like I am reassigning machineList[j]=readLine. Thus, even if the value of readLine changes, it shouldn't change the value in machineList[j]. Again, I am new to C, so I realize my code semantics could be awful- anything is helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strtok` modifies the original string by replacing the delimiters with null bytes.

I assume `machineList` is an array of pointers to `char`, so this:

```
machineList[j] = readLine;
```

...makes `machineList[j]` a pointer to `readLine`. Then this:

```
day = strtok(readLine, " ,");
```

...modifies `readLine`, which also modifies `machineList[j]` since it points to it. You'll want to make a copy instead:

```
// allocate machineList[j]
strcpy(machineList[j], readLine);
```

If you don't make a copy, when your `while` loop ends, `machineList` will basically be an array of dangling pointers.

Comment: Thank you! Pointers are probably the thing I understand the least, in all of this, so it does not surprise me that I was doing something wrong that involved them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies here

```
machineList[j] = readLine;
```

This does **not** copy the whole char string to `machineList[i]`, but only the reference (pointer, memory address) to `readLine`. Thus if you modify `readLine`, `machineList[j]` will still reference this modified string.

If you want to copy the strings, use `strcpy()`:

```
strcpy(machineList[j], readLine);
```

Don't forget to allocate memory for `machineList` if you didn't (before copying):

```
machineList[i] = malloc(strlen(readLine) + 1);
```

Resuming:

```
machineList[i] = malloc(strlen(readLine) + 1);
strcpy(machineList[j], readLine);
```

Or, as Arkadiy points out, use `strdup()` to combine allocation and copying in one sentence:

```
machineList[i] = strdup(readLine);
```

When finished, don't forget to free the memory:

```
free(machineList[i]); // For each i
```

Comment: use strdup to combine memory allocation and copying.

Comment: Thanks, my C is oxidated :)

Comment: Thank you both! Can I still use the free() function to deallocate the memory assigned using strdup()?

Comment: No, you can't, you **MUST** :)

Answer (score 0):

```
while(fgets(readLine, 100, inFile) != NULL) { 
    printf("j = %d\n", j);
    puts(readLine);
```

Consider that here, the address of `readLine` is 0x1234abcd.

```
    machineList[j] = readLine;
```

Now, `machineList[j]` contains the value(and hence points to) 0x1234abcd

```
    puts(machineList[j]); //the value of machineList[j] at this point is equal
                          // to the current readLine
```

and so, you get correct answers.

```
    int i=0;

    day = strtok(readLine, " ,");
```

Unfortunately, here, the value at 0x1234abcd changes(because `readLine` changes). Remember, `machineList[j]` points to `readLine` which is 0x1234abcd address

```
    puts(machineList[j]); //the value of machineList[j] at this point is no
                          //longer what it was at the previously noted point
```

`:-(` Unfortunately you get unwanted results.

Instead, you can use `strdup()` (not STDC) that creates a new string in the memory, duplicates the data in `readLine` and returns the pointer to the memory.

Alternatively, you can do what it does by first `malloc()`ing the string, followed by using `strcpy()`